# Facebook Graph API / OAuth token -- retrieving user ID for gray/advertising account

Tags: api, facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

In my application I retrieve OAuth token as per standard procedure. I know that the proper way to 'resolve' token to user information (including ID) is via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<token>
```

However this method appears to return 'false' for the so-called gray/advertising Facebook accounts. It so happens that I also need to deal with such accounts.

How can I retrieve user ID or any other useful user information for such accounts if the only information I have is OAuth access token? Should I resort to parsing the token to extract user ID a la http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still have no idea how to do it via Graph API.

Via 'legacy REST API' you can at least invoke this: users.getLoggedInUser

This will give you user ID (uid).